# Is FastCGI OK in 2021?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, perl, mod-fcgid

It appears most discussions about FastCGI here are frozen from nearly a decade ago and so as someone who just decided to start making use of it, I'm wondering if I am making a mistake with unforeseen security or compatibility issues ahead of me. Here are a few things that prompted my concern:

- It appears the libraries for it such as the Perl CPAN module, have not been updated in years.
- The [Perl module complains about UTF-8 output years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005104/how-to-force-fastcgi-to-encode-form-data-as-utf-8-as-cgi-pm-has-option) after that became normal and the lack of updates don't seem to offer a lot of hope for a fix.
- I also noted that [Mojolicious spun off its FastCGI support](https://github.com/arpadszasz/mojo-server-fastcgi) some years ago for not meeting the quality standards of the codebase. I don't presently use Mojolicious, but I found that notable.

Have a chosen a dead end by finally waking up to FastCGI this year?

I have clients who use PHP, so I'm interested in PHP support, but I'm **primarily** interested in if there is a better future-oriented alternative to use that supports Perl, which is the language I use for most of the CGI programs on the server. Maybe I'm overthinking it and FastCGI will be just fine. So far, I'm using `mod_fcgid` with Apache, although my goal is to get it running directly with Nginx, which I'm already using to serve static content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastCGI is the only interface to run PHP scripts directly with nginx, so that is still very much valid.

However, the relevance depends on particular language. Perl is unknown area to me, so I cannot comment on that.

Comment: Thank you! That helps -- I just wanted to make sure I wasn't building on something that was completely forgotten. If anyone would benefit, I found a solution to the UTF-8 issue in this patch that I'm linking to the line number of: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L1312